# R - I have a procedure to extract the day of the week from an event time, now I want to change it to extract the hour of the day of the event time

Tags: r, time, hour, weekday

I have the code to look at a dataframe and determine the day of the week an event started (started_at).

Now I want to chart the hour of the day the event started on a 24 hour clock.

To me it should be as simple as changing the "weekdays" function to a corresponding "hours" function if one exists
Then changing the

```
    factor( levels=c("0:00","01:00...))
```

Here is the code that I think should work if I new what to replace the

```
    lubridate:hour()
```

function with

```
   df_mc_hour <- df_clean_distances %>% 
    mutate(hour = factor(lubridate::hour(df_clean_distances$started_at),
    levels=c("0:00","1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00", "5:00","6:00", 
    "7:00", "8:00","9:00","10:00","11:00", "12:00","13:00","14:00", 
  
 "15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00", 
  "24:00")), 
  mc=c(member_casual)) %>% tabyl(hour, member_casual)
  df_mc_hour
```

This gives me the following table so it is partially working

```
    hour  casual  member
    0:00       0       0
    1:00       0       0
    2:00       0       0
    3:00       0       0
    4:00       0       0
    5:00       0       0
    6:00       0       0
    7:00       0       0
    8:00       0       0
    9:00       0       0
   10:00       0       0
   11:00       0       0
   12:00       0       0
   13:00       0       0
   14:00       0       0
   15:00       0       0
   16:00       0       0
   17:00       0       0
   18:00       0       0
   19:00       0       0
   20:00       0       0
   21:00       0       0
   22:00       0       0
   23:00       0       0
   24:00       0       0
  <NA> 1424941 2049543
```

I tired to use

```
   format(Sys.time(), format = "%H")
```

but that is not working. I think it is because start_at is a POSIXct type.

Here is my second attempt

```
   df_mc_hour <- df_clean_distances %>% 
   mutate(hour = factor(format(df_clean_distances$started_at, format = 
   "%H"),
    levels=c("0:00","1:00", "2:00", "3:00", "4:00", "5:00","6:00", "7:00", 
     "8:00","9:00","10:00","11:00", "12:00","13:00","14:00", "15:00", 
    "16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00", "21:00","22:00","23:00", 
    "24:00")),
     mc=c(member_casual)) %>% 
     tabyl(hour, member_casual)

    df_mc_hour
```

This above was changed to this below

```
   df_mc_hour <- df_clean_distances %>% 
   mutate(hour = factor(format(df_clean_distances$started_at, format = "% H"), levels=c("00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11",12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23)), mc=c(member_casual)) 
    %>% tabyl(hour, member_casual)
```

The third attempt gives this output -- Success.

```
   hour casual member
     00  22430  12100
     01  13979   6796
     02   7686   3661
     03   4114   2319
     04   3434   3574
     05   5400  17244
     06  12864  56244
     07  23101  94422
     08  31710 102599
     09  40708  86997
     10  58289  92457
     11  80432 115845
     12  97999 136178
     13 106561 135697
     14 113327 135849
     15 119440 150640
     16 126388 179952
     17 139725 215323
     18 125940 186883
     19  96204 130136
     20  67605  79977
     21  48808  47913
     22  43689  33737
     23  35108  23000
```

Here is the str() output.

```
   Classes ‘tabyl’ and 'data.frame':    24 obs. of  3 variables:
   $ hour  : Factor w/ 24 levels "00","01","02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
   ...
   $ casual: num  22430 13979 7686 4114 3434 ...
   $ member: num  12100 6796 3661 2319 3574 ...
   - attr(*, "core")='data.frame':  24 obs. of  3 variables:
   ..$ hour  : Factor w/ 24 levels "00","01","02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
  10 ...
   ..$ casual: num [1:24] 22430 13979 7686 4114 3434 ...
   ..$ member: num [1:24] 12100 6796 3661 2319 3574 ...
   - attr(*, "tabyl_type")= chr "two_way"
   - attr(*, "var_names")=List of 2
    ..$ row: chr "hour"
   ..$ col: chr "member_casual"
```

Here is the function I have that is working to calculate ridership by day of week comparing casual to members

```
##day of the week

df_mc_day <- df_clean_distances %>% 
  mutate(weekday = weekdays(df_clean_distances$started_at),
         mc=c(member_casual)) %>% 
  tabyl(weekday, member_casual)

df_mc_day <- df_clean_distances %>% 
  mutate(weekday = factor(weekdays(df_clean_distances$started_at),
                          levels=c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")),
         mc=c(member_casual)) %>% 
  tabyl(weekday, member_casual)
df_mc_day
```

```
    weekday casual member
    Monday    150953 267013
    Tuesday   145036 284001
    Wednesday 158168 304679
    Thursday  166103 300030
    Friday    208234 306058
    Saturday  334592 322765
    Sunday    261855 264997
```

Plot the days of the weeks comparison

```
   df_mc_day %>% adorn_totals("row")
   p <- ggplot() + geom_col( data=df_mc_day, aes(x=weekday, y=member)) 
   p

   df_mc_day %>%
    pivot_longer(cols =-weekday) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=weekday, y=value, fill=name)) +
    geom_col( position = 'dodge') + theme_light() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE)) +
    labs( title ="Rider Membership by Day of the week") +
    scale_color_brewer( type="seq", palette = "Spectral")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you rework some of the question text formatting? It is really hard to understand. I'm sorry, but I did not read everything, as it is very cluttered. If you need to find out the hour, use `lubridate::hour` on any POSIXt object.

Comment: Just like `weekdays(Sys.time())` will tell you today is `"Tuesday"`, then `format(Sys.time(), format = "%H")` will tell you that it is currently `"16"` (since it's 4:46pm my local time). That means your "hours" function may be as simple as `hours <- function(z) format(z, "%H")` (assuming its input is `POSIXt`).

Answer (score 0):

So the answer came about, shown above, with what was suggested by @r2evans. A little experimenting and looking at the str() gave me the clues needed.